# Is there a reason this human character's name sounds Tymbrimi?

Tags: david-brin, the-uplift-war

It's time to play Guess The Human!
Here's a list of characters mentioned in *The Uplift War*

Athaclena, Ma'chutallil, Mathicluanna, Oshoyoythuna, Oth'thushutn, Prathachulthorn, Thlufallthreela, Uthacalthing

Seven are Tymbrimi and one is human.   I doubt you can tell which is the human unless you have read the book.   (Pick one before spoiling yourself.)

> Answer: It's Prathachulthorn

All the names are four or five syllables and all contain the sound *th*.

Furthermore, the character in question's name is not typically

> South Asian

as described (although I guess the first syllable or two are not terribly unusual for that culture).

Is there an explanation for this choice of name in- or out-of-universe?

Comment: Being one of the first extra-terrestrial races met by Humanity, and with the Tymbrimi being an ally of Humanity, I can see names moving from one species to another with prolonged interaction.

Comment: @Thaddeus:   Plausible, but needs evidence.   Is there any?   Brin usually makes offhand remarks in the text about things like this that he intends but doesn't want to go into.

Comment: Not enough time left in my day to do the research for a question like this one. Good luck. I hope you can find a satisfying answer...

Comment: I always thought Prathaculthorn was meant to be from India or therebouts. To Americans, "South Asian" tends to mean Cambodia, Vietnam, etc., while to the Brits I think it means India and surrounding countries.

Comment: @JoeL. I don't know this canon but Prathaculthorn sounds nothing like any existant South Asian or South East Asian name, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [chatting](https://mobile.twitter.com/DavidBrin/status/598240867447517184?cn=cmVwbHk%3D&refsrc=email) with my very good friend David Brin, I found a moment to ask your question. The short answer is that Prathaculthorn's name is **not** Tymbrimi, in fact it's a traditionally Thai name, or at least a [Westernised version thereof](https://www.cpp.edu/~pronunciation/thai.html).

> **@Answerguesser** - *Quick Uplift question:
>
>   Why does Prathachulthorn have such an obviously Tymbrimi name?*
>
> **@DavidBrin** - *Heh! Well, in fact, Tymbrimi names are kinda like those in Thailand.... ;-)*

Comment: Wow!  It's great that you know him and asked.   But I don't know what to make of that answer.   It kind of seems like his answer was flip or a joke, especially with the smiley.   So I don't really know if this is a real answer or not.

Comment: @Thepopmachine - I think it was intended seriously. The name sounds a bit Thai.

Comment: Hmmm.   I didn't buy it until I read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_common_surnames_in_Asia#Thailand   "There are no common Thai surnames. Surnames were largely introduced to Thai culture only by the 1913 Surname Act.[18] The law is not allow to create any surname that duplicated with any existing surnames.[19] Under Thai law, only one family can create any given surname: any two people of the same surname must be related, and it is very rare for two people to share the same full name. In one sample of 45,665 names, 81% of family names were unique.[20]"

Comment: And see https://www.cpp.edu/~pronunciation/thai.html

Comment: ....So the bottom line is, he seems to be saying it is a coincidence that Thai and Tymbrimi names are similar.

Comment: A little improvement on this based on our links and I'd accept this rather old answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I've copied in the pronunciation link. I'm honestly not sure what I'd add extra beyond what the Voice of God has already said on the subject.